# media store gets the path to a song but the media player is unable to play it(Android studio)

Tags: java, android, uri, media-player, mediastore

I am making an app in android studio that requires playing music from the phone's storage
the music is within this class:
public class AudioModel {

````
        String aPath;
        String aName;
        String aAlbum;
        String aArtist;

        public String getaPath() {
            return aPath;
        }
        public void setaPath(String aPath) {
            this.aPath = aPath;
        }
        public String getaName() {
            return aName;
        }
        public void setaName(String aName) {
            this.aName = aName;
        }
        public String getaAlbum() {
            return aAlbum;
        }
        public void setaAlbum(String aAlbum) {
            this.aAlbum = aAlbum;
        }
        public String getaArtist() {
            return aArtist;
        }
        public void setaArtist(String aArtist) {
            this.aArtist = aArtist;
        }
    }  ```
````

and I get it from this method:

````
public List<AudioModel> getAllAudioFromDevice(final Context context) {
        final List<AudioModel> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();


        Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST,};
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                AudioModel audioModel = new AudioModel();
                String path = c.getString(0);
                String name = c.getString(1);
                String album = c.getString(2);
                String artist = c.getString(3);

                audioModel.setaName(name);
                audioModel.setaAlbum(album);
                audioModel.setaArtist(artist);
                audioModel.setaPath(path);

                Log.e("Name :" + name, " Album :" + album);
                Log.e("Path :" + path, " Artist :" + artist);

                tempAudioList.add(audioModel);
            }
            c.close();
        }

        return tempAudioList;
    } ```
**//and that is used to get the path to the song like this**
``` @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView fileView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.work);

        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);

        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(getAllAudioFromDevice(this).get(2).aPath);

        fileView.setText(getAllAudioFromDevice(this).get(2).aPath);

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();

                try{
                    mp.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,myUri);
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setVolume(0.5f,0.5f);

                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            }
        });



    } ``
````

when the program is executed gets the address of the song and displays it but when the play button is clicked it does not register as a valid path
I know that the should be valid because it's displayed on the text view and matches up with the one I know exists on the phone

**I have tried many things including:**

converting the URI to a string,

converting the URI into a string and adding"file:///"or"file://" to the beginning,

attempting to set the media player in a separate thread,

searching and finding the address manually and inputting it into the code as a string,

I think that the problem is somewhere in the "getAllAudioFromDevice()" method

I am desperate please help!

Comment: `Log.e("Path :" + path, " Artist :" + artist)`. Please tell what is printed.

Comment: In your while loop add following code: `if (!newFile(path).exists() ) continue; if ( ! new File(path).canRead()) continue;` Put it before you add your model to the list.

Comment: Please remove  Android Studio from the subject of your post.